# Mix opened Excel VBA and VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Is it possible to connect opened Excel file from separate VBScript program and real-time update cells (or do something other things )?

Comment: Need a lot more information.

Comment: some similar functionality like JavaScript does

Comment: Still need to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think editing with real-time update is possible with VBScript.

Here's what you *can* do:

- Edit an Excel file using CreateObject("Excel.Application") - see [here](https://gist.github.com/simply-coded/758e2557ccd1a55b46765d8bb1099ec6) for details. As mentioned, this will not cause real-time update and the excel file probably needs to be closed.
- **Use VBA**: Excel has Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) integrated. With VBA you can do anything that's possible with VBScript and much more. To open the VBA Editor, press Alt+F11 in your Excel file. Docs are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/getting-started-with-vba-in-office), sample tutorial is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/).